# Unable to assert that list contains a map

Tags: hamcrest

I want to use hamcrest to compare a list which has map entries.

```
    Map<String, String> aMapWithCertainEntries = new HashMap();
    aMapWithCertainEntries.put("entry1Key", "entry1Value");
    aMapWithCertainEntries.put("entry2Key", "entry2Value");

    List<Map<String,String>> listToTest = Arrays.asList(new Map[] {aMapWithCertainEntries});

    //I want to assert that list has a map with entry1Key, entry2Key keys and corresponding values
    assertThat(listToTest, hasItem(??))
    System.out.println();
```

In the place marked ?? I want to create the right matcher to assert that my map contains specific keys and values.

Any help/pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you're trying to assert

Comment: @SkinnyJ, I just made some edits. Comment if the example is sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to assert that the List contains a Map whose **entire** contents are as expected, the easiest approach is:

```
Map<String, String> expectedEntries = ....;
assertThat(listToTest, hasItem(expectedEntries));
```

However, if you want to ensure that the List contains a Map which contains the given **subset** of entries, you will need to take one of the following approaches:

**Approach 1: Create a Custom Matcher**

```
assertThat(listToTest, hasItem(new CustomTypeSafeMatcher<Map<String,String>>("an entrySet that contains " + expectedEntries.entrySet()) {
    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(Map<String, String> o) {
        return hasItems(expectedEntries.entrySet().toArray()).matches(o.entrySet());
    }
}));
```

**Approach 2: Assert on each Map's `entrySet` rather than on the Maps themselves**

```
assertThat(listToTest.stream().map(Map::entrySet).collect(Collectors.toList()),
    hasItem(hasItems(expectedEntries.entrySet().toArray(new Map.Entry[expectedEntries.size()]))));
```

Comment: Thanks! I chose to write a custom matcher. (Not on Java 8 yet and so no Approach 2 yet).